# Flutter Slidable SlidableAction Calling onPressed even when it has not been pressed

Tags: flutter, dart, dismissible

I am using a library called [flutter_slidable](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable)  . Below is my fetchItems method

```
static Future<List<Item>> fetchItems(String url) async {
    try {
      // pub spec yaml http:
      // import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
      final response = await http.get(
          Uri.parse(
              url),
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer tltsp6dmnbif01jy9xfo9ssn4620u89xhuwcm5t3",
          }) /*.timeout(const Duration(seconds: Config.responseTimeOutInSeconds))*/;

      final List<Item> itemsList;

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        itemsList = json
            .decode(response.body)
        // In event of failure return line below
        //.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()
            .map<Item>((json) => Item.fromJson(json))
            .toList();
      } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
        itemsList = [];
      } else {
        itemsList = [];
      }
      return itemsList;
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        Logger().wtf(
            "FetchItemsException $e \n\nResponseStatusCode ${statusCode!}");
      }

      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

And below is the code for my page that i populate

```
class ClassListWithSearchOnAppBarCustomCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const ClassListWithSearchOnAppBarCustomCard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ClassListWithSearchOnAppBarCustomCardState createState() =>
      _ClassListWithSearchOnAppBarCustomCardState();
}

class _ClassListWithSearchOnAppBarCustomCardState
    extends State<ClassListWithSearchOnAppBarCustomCard> {
  List<Item>? itemsList;

  Future populateItemsList() async {
    final itemsList = await AsyncFutures.fetchItems(
        "https://api.json-generator.com/templates/ueOoUwh5r44G/data");

    setState(() {
      this.itemsList = itemsList;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    populateItemsList();
  }

  onSearch(String searchValue) {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
          leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back,
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
          title: Container(
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: (value) => onSearch(value),
              cursorHeight: 21.0,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.grey[850],
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  prefix: Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: Colors.grey.shade500,
                  ),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                      borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                  hintStyle:
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.grey.shade500),
                  hintText: "Search"),
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                if (itemsList == null) {
                  return iconProgressIndicator();
                } else {
                  return RefreshIndicator(
                      // background color
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      // refresh circular progress indicator color
                      color: Colors.green,
                      onRefresh: () async {
                        setState(() {
                          populateItemsList();
                        });
                      },
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: itemsList!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          // flutter_slidable: ^1.2.0
                          // import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';
                          return Slidable(
                            // Specify whether the slider is dismissible
                            key: const ValueKey(1),
                            // Sliding from left to right
                            startActionPane: ActionPane(
                              // Types of Motion
                              // Behind Motion, Drawer Motion, Scroll Motion , Stretch Motion
                              motion: const DrawerMotion(),
                              // dismissible: DismissiblePane(onDismissed: () {
                              //   onDismissedRemoveItem(
                              //       itemsList![index].id ?? "");
                              // }),
                              children: [
                                // Start this side with delete action if you have already implemented dismissible
                                // If Start with other slidable action create a new method for the slidable with a build context
                                SlidableAction(
                                  onPressed: deleteSlidableAction(
                                      context, itemsList![index].id ?? ""),
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.red.shade500,
                                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                  icon: Icons.delete,
                                  label: 'Delete',
                                ),
                                SlidableAction(
                                  onPressed: dialogSlidableAction(
                                      context, itemsList![index].id ?? ""),
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent.shade400,
                                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                  icon: Icons.check_box_outline_blank,
                                  label: 'Dialog',
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            child: myCustomCardWidget(
                                itemsList![index].id ?? "",
                                itemsList![index].title ?? "",
                                itemsList![index].subTitle ?? '',
                                itemsList![index].imageUrl ??
                                    Config.nullNetworkImage),
                          );
                        },
                      ));
                }
              },
            ),
          )
        ]));
  }

  deleteSlidableAction(BuildContext context, String? itemId) {
    
    setState(() {
      itemsList!.removeWhere((item) => item.id == itemId);
    });
  }

  dialogSlidableAction(BuildContext context, String? itemId) {
    print(itemId);
  }

  void onDismissedRemoveItem(String itemId) {
    setState(() {
      itemsList!.removeWhere((item) => item.id == itemId);
    });
  }
}
```

The problem i am having is that onPressed of SlidableAction for both Delete and Dialog are being called even before they are pressed and the populated list items are all removed

Answer (score 5):

```
   SlidableAction(
                                  // An action can be bigger than the others.
                                  onPressed: (BuildContext context){
                                    _yesPost(forMeList[i]["postID"]);
                                  },
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                  icon: Icons.check_circle_outline,
                                  label: 'Yes',
                                ),
```

try to add BuildContext.
that worked for me.

---